# Find observations where a date falls between 2 other dates, then add a row counting these observations. - R

Tags: r

Apologies for the vague question title, I was struggling with how to ask.

I have something like this:

```
df_A

patient_number     visit_date
1                   2/2/2003
1                   5/4/2002
2                   4/15/1999
2                   4/30/1996
```

and then another data frame

```
df_B

patient_number     medication     start_date     end_date
1                    M             1/2/2002         NA
1                    N             3/7/1999        12/16/2000
1                    O             4/3/2002        7/12/2004
2                    N             5/8/1992        11/4/1997
```

I want to add a row to the first data frame that counts the number of active medications that the person was on at the time of the visit, like this:

```
data_A

patient_number     visit_date      number_meds
1                   2/2/2003            2
1                   5/4/2002            2
2                   4/15/1999           0
2                   4/30/1996           1
```

I think I need to filter the medications that have a corresponding visit date within the medication start and end date, and then count the rows. I just can't seem to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I notice a trend, alex: your questions mention having *"dates"* yet your sample data appears to always have *"strings"*, not dates. Your current formats will not sort correctly, and will not calculate differences. I strongly suggest that somewhere *early* in your data import process, convert them to proper `Date`-class objects with `as.Date` or similar. It seems that this and your other recent question both have answerers suggesting the same step.

Comment: If you don't like R's default of `%Y-%m-%d`, that's fine, but ... realize that R only shows it in one format. If you want it shown in a different format in a report, then convert it to strings immediately before rendering it in a report. But until then, I suggest all date-like objects should be `Date`-class objects, allowing all sorts of operations on them to "just work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your dates are `Date`. If there is a missing `end_date` this can be indicated as `Inf` for use with a join (assumes patient still taking the medication ongoing).

```
df_A$visit_date <- as.Date(df_A$visit_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
df_B$start_date <- as.Date(df_B$start_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
df_B$end_date <- as.Date(df_B$end_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
df_B$end_date[is.na(df_B$end_date)] <- as.Date(Inf)
```

Using `fuzzyjoin` package, you can join both data frames on `patient_number` and include medications that have a `visit_date` that falls between `start_date` and `end_date`. Using `group_by` and `summarise`, total up the unique medications for each patient and visit date combination.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)

df_A %>%
  fuzzy_left_join(
    df_B,
    by = c("patient_number", "visit_date" = "start_date", "visit_date" = "end_date"),
    match_fun = c(`==`, `>=`, `<=`)
  ) %>%
  group_by(patient_number.x, visit_date) %>%
  summarise(number_meds = n_distinct(medication, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**Edit**: As an alternative, you can use `sqldf` package. In this case, your SQL statement will include a left join on `patient_number`.

```
library(sqldf)

result <- sqldf("select a.*, b.medication, b.start_date, b.end_date
                 from df_A a left join df_B b
                 on a.patient_number = b.patient_number and
                   a.visit_date between b.start_date and b.end_date")

result %>%
  group_by(patient_number, visit_date) %>%
  summarise(number_meds = n_distinct(medication, na.rm = TRUE))
```

**Output**

```
  patient_number.x visit_date number_meds
             <int> <date>           <int>
1                1 2002-05-04           2
2                1 2003-02-02           2
3                2 1996-04-30           1
4                2 1999-04-15           0
```

Comment: when I try to run it it ends up crashing, is there a way to do it without the fuzzyjoin package?

Comment: @alex Are you able to install and load the `fuzzyjoin` library ok?

Comment: If you get an error, and/or can describe the problem further, maybe I can help - let me know.

Comment: yes! it loads okay but then it just runs forever until it crashes

Comment: Did it work with your test data above? Or just a problem with your actual dataframe?

Comment: @alex See my edited answer for an alternative with `sqldf`. In addition, if there are still problems, describe your actual data a bit more (size and structure), or perhaps use `dput(head(df_A))` and same for `df_B` to review actual data used. I suppose we can also try a `data.table` solution too...

Comment: The error I am getting with sqldif is "Error: near "and": syntax error"

Comment: @alex Not sure why you received an error. Are you using the same data frames as above? With the same names? Are you able to reproduce the error using the exact same code and data above? I reran my code using `sqldf` and the above data frames `df_A` and `df_B` including the code I added to covert to dates with `as.Date`, and did not get any errors.